# How to come out of AOAP Mode in Android

Tags: android

I am working on an Android Application.

The Application requires to check whether the [Android device supports Android Open Accessory Protocol (AOAP)](https://source.android.com/accessories/protocol.html) mode and if it supports then the device should go into AOAP mode, followed by that some operation is done.

When the operation is completed, the application should come out of AOAP mode.

The commands used to do the above tasks are below:

1. **Command 51** -> It is used to check whether AOAP mode is supported.
2. **Command 52** -> It is used to send informations about the device.
3. **Command 53** -> It is used to make the Android Device to go into
   AOAP mode.

**But I need a command or a way which would make the device come out of AOAP mode.**

Comment: Why my question was given a down vote ? May I know ?

Comment: The below comment goes directly to the one who gave a down vote to this question !
If my question was answered and followed by that it was down voted then it makes sense, and without answering if it gets down voted then it is complete non sense.
What the StackOverflow admins are doing ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using a package named **libusb**, you can find it in this [link](http://www.libusb.org/), for sending the Command 51, 52 and 53 so that the Android Device switches to AOAP mode.

To come out of the AOAP mode it is enough to just call libusb_reset_device with the right Device Handle. The device will re-enumerate to MTP device without fail.

Answer (score 1):

The consistency of libusb_reset_device is not good, it doesn't send the device to MTP always.

A note from Android Documentation for AOAP [LINK](https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/aoa.html)

*"To switch from AOA to MTP, the accessory must first disconnect the `USB device` (either physically or in an electrically equivalent way) then reconnect using MTP."*

Hence, to conclude `libusb`_reset_device is not recommended when you are doing rigorous testing, try to find a way to implement "*electrically equivalent way*" to come out of `AOAP`.